# angularJS communicating with API

Tags: json, angularjs

hi i am new completely new to AngularJS.
Trying to communicate with a JSON API. The API is beign called i am getting results bit the results are not getting filled into the view.

Here is the view:

```
    <div >

   <div data-ng-repeat="order in ordersResult.orders">
       {{error}}
       <fieldset class="fieldset">

            <legend>
            <b>{{order.klant.straat}} {{order.klant.huisnummer}} - {{order.klant.bedrijf}}</b>
            </legend>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <th>Broodje</th><th>Aantal</th>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="(tag,aantal) in order.broodjes" data-ng-click="check()">
                    <td>{{tag}}</td><td>{{aantal}}x</td>
                </tr>


               <tr data-ng-repeat="(tag,opmerkingen) in order.broodjesSpeciaal">
                   <td>{{tag}}</td><td><span ng-repeat="opmerking in opmerkingen">1x {{opmerking}}<br></span></td>
               </tr>
            </table>

       </fieldset>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Controller:

```
app.controller('BezorgController', function ($scope, $resource) {


function getToday(){
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
    //return mm+""+dd+""+yyyy;

    return "22052013";
}






$scope.ordersRequest = $resource('http://www.movieapphd.com/bertus/api.1.0.0/order/bezorging/:day?key=:key',
    {day: getToday(), key: API_KEY },
    {get: {method: "JSONP"}}
);
$scope.ordersResult = $scope.ordersRequest.get();

if($scope.ordersResult.size == 0){
    $scope.error = "Geen bezorgingen vandaag";
}
```

});

Here is the json that i get:

```
{
   "orders":[
      {
         "klant":{
            "bedrijf":"X",
            "straat":"Haarlemmer",
            "huisnummer":"8"
         },
         "broodjes":{
            "0.0":0
         },
         "broodjesSpeciaal":{
            "0.0":[
               "nothing"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "klant":{
            "bedrijf":"Anouk Beauty Gangbang",
            "straat":"Haarlemmer",
            "huisnummer":"220"
         },
         "broodjes":{
            "0.0":0,
            "1.1":2,
            "1.2":1,
            "2.3":1
         },
         "broodjesSpeciaal":{
            "0.0":[
               "nothing"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "klant":{
            "bedrijf":"Hans Kazan GoochelTrucs",
            "straat":"Haarlemmer",
            "huisnummer":"222"
         },
         "broodjes":{
            "0.0":0,
            "1.1":2,
            "1.2":2,
            "2.3":1,
            "3.1":1
         },
         "broodjesSpeciaal":{
            "0.0":[
               "nothing"
            ],
            "2.3":[
               "zonder stukjes",
               "met extra stukjes"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Uhhh whats up with "Anouk Beauty Gangbang" in your JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to change the method to `get` since the API is located on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

From the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat), you can't use that syntax for arrays, and it appears sometimes `broodjes` and `broodjesSpecial` are arrays, and sometimes associative arrays. Also, in the one case where `broodjes` is an associative array there are no keys.

Comment: Check my edit, please. I have changed to api to return an object called orders and give it an array.

Comment: Still not consistent: `"broodjes":[]` and `"broodjes":{"3.1":1, "1.2":1}`. You'll need to make sure that you make those look the same.

Comment: is that why im getting the following error also: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : /bertus/api.1.0.0/order/bezorging/22052013/?key=

Comment: it makes no difference if i make the response consistent. look at edit